# a word/phrase for someone who appears bad on the surface but is actually good (in terms of character)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

my transition sentence after describing the actions and choices of a few characters: "On the surface their character can be construed as contemptible— squandering their intelligence and ability for lavishness, capitulation, and banditry."

now I'm trying to transition that these actions that "appeared" contemptible were actually a means to a greater good.

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word, phrase to describe a kind but corrupt person?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406937/is-there-a-word-phrase-to-describe-a-kind-but-corrupt-person)

Comment: @Scott Not convinced it's a dupe - this is for someone that isn't corrupt, even if they afloat to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review for [*Crazy Like a Fox*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GJG2O78xdbkC&dq=crazy%20like%20a%20fox&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjttbC2h4naAhVG1WMKHf6NAt0Q6AEIQjAF), One Principal's Triumph in the Inner City:

> Wow, this guy really is crazy. His tactics are unorthidox [sic], but incredibly effective. I'll testify that his methods are flawed, distasteful, and crude but the take away is powerful!

From *Merriam-Webster*:

> Definition of [crazy like a fox](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crazy%20like%20a%20fox): appearing foolish or strange but actually very clever

Answer (score 1):

Gentle giant

> Someone who is very large and strong but has a quiet and gentle
>   nature.
>  "At first, I was afraid of the big, burly man covered in
>   tattoos, but when I saw him rescue that kitten from the tree, I
>   realized he was just a gentle giant."
>   [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+gentle+giant)

Answer (score 1):

A ***sheep in wolf's clothing***, usually used for comic effect.

A play on the opposite (and more usual) ***wolf in sheep's clothing***, natch.